# Accessing angular controller defined within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to wrap ng-controller within a directive and access its attributes within the html. However, I can't get this to work.

This is my app.js file content:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myDirective', function()
{
   transclude: true,
   template: '<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl" ng-transclude></div>'
});
```

I am not able to access any attribute (say message) defined within MyController. This piece of code on my html page does not work (i.e. message does not get printed):

```
<my-directive>
    {{ ctrl.message }}
</my-directive>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: if you omit the ng-controller="MyController as ctrl" part you should be fine since you are not scoping the directive. Doesn't look like you need that part

Comment: I need this because my html needs to display ctrl.message

Comment: Thanks @EdgarMartinez, but not sure if this is the correct link.

Comment: why not wrap the directive with the controller and you have it on template?

Comment: I am trying to make this (and some related code) easily reusable by packaging into directives. It would be somewhat like: <my-directive><my-link>A</my-link><my-link>B<my-link></my-directive>

Comment: You've probably noticed by now, but there is an extra " after ng-transclude in your directive template.

Comment: Yup, I just fixed it (did not copy the originally provided snippet from my IDE). But, the question is still relevant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from Scope';
  $scope.me = this;
  this.scope = $scope;
  this.message = 'Hello from Controller';
  $scope.click = function(scope) {
    alert('Alert message!!!');
  }
  this.click = function(){
    alert('Controllers click!!!')
  }
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      ctrl: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-click="ctrl.scope.click()">'
      +'Scope message:{{ctrl.scope.message}}<br/>Controller message: {{ctrl.message}}<br />'
      + '</div><div ng-click="ctrl.click()">Click me!</div>';
  }
});
```

You can try to do it this way... hope it helps you...
Plunker: [see all code](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3P0mnHkKT1kthipgwil?p=preview)